# Different results when a function is evaluated in the REPL than in a program

Tags: user-interface, clojure, lazy-evaluation, read-eval-print-loop

I have a feeling the answer to my question is something to do with Clojure's lazy evaluation (which I am still fuzzy on...)

So I have a function:

```
(defn fix-str-old [string]
  (let [words (->> string
                   (clojure.string/split-lines) 
                   (map #(clojure.string/replace % #"\W" "")))]
    (apply str (interleave words (repeat " ")))))
```

Basically it just takes a wacky sentence with non-alphanumeric chars, chars, return characters, line feeds etc in place of a space and turns it into a regular sentence. The reason for this if you're curious is that whenever I try to copy out of certain PDFs, it puts line feeds and other mysterious characters in between the words.

Here is an example:

```
(fix-str "A 
  block 
  of    
  SQL   
  statements    
  that  
  must  
  all   
  complete  
   successfully 
  before    
  returning 
  or    
  changing  
  anything  ")

==> "A block of SQL statements that must all complete  successfully before returning or changing anything"
```

It works fine in the REPL but when it is evaluated inside of a little swing gui you get this:

```
"AblockofSQLstatementsthatmustallcompletesuccessfullybeforereturningorchanginganything "
```

(note the space at the end of the string)

I was pretty sure that this was because of some gap in my understanding of how Clojure handles lazy seqs so I whipped up this function that just does regex operations.

```
(defn fix-str [string]
  (-> string
      (clojure.string/replace #"[ \t\n\r]+" " ")
      (clojure.string/replace #"[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]" "")
      (clojure.string/trimr)))
```

which isn't lazy and works fine in both the REPL and in the GUI.

Note: I also tried putting doall statements in various places in the original function that I though might make sense to make sure it forced evaluation of the lazy seqs but I couldn't get it to work either.

So my question isn't really if the first way is a good way to fix the strings, but rather why am I getting a different result in the REPL and in my GUI.

Comment: As Alex said, it works the same in the REPL or while running normally, your input string from your GUI is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laziness should not be your problem here, because `(apply str ...)` forces the output from `map` to be realized (and because there's no bindings here, which is usually your first clue that laziness is the culprit).

Looks to me like there's something funky going on with the line-endings coming from the GUI, and that `split-lines` is not splitting anything. That function splits on `\n` or `\r\n` - maybe somehow you're getting `\r` as line-endings from the GUI? You can verify this by adding this to the beginning of your `fix-str` function:

```
(doseq [c string] (println (int c)))
```

Comment: Good call on checking the GUI string...when I copy the string from the document to the REPL it looks like above, however the GUI puts 9 32 32 160 between all the words (which is horizontal-tab space space non-breaking-space), none of which are broken by split-lines.

Comment: Nice tip about bindings being a clue that laziness is an issue as well.